# When did swamp/wetland conversion first begin, and what were the early methods for doing so?

Tags: technology, agriculture, geography, construction

I have been trying to do some research into the early history of humans using wetlands, but haven't had much luck. As I understand it so far, there are a number of methods of "wetland conversion", processes in which humans alter some properties of a wetland in order for it to be more useful for human purposes.

Some methods are more drastic alterations that others. It seems there are some farming techniques that grow crops in wetlands while preserving some aspects of the wetland's nature. More drastic options might include entirely draining or filling a swamp or wetland in order to build things on it.

Correct me if there's anything I've said that's not quite right.

I am curious when and where different methods of wetland conversion first began. So when and where did it first begin? What technologies were used? Did more drastic conversion methods come later? If so, when and where did those begin?

Comment: Probably not the earliest case but salt marsh drainage in the Netherlands goes back 1000 years and was greatly advanced with wind pumps by the sixteenth century or so: https://www.jstor.org/stable/4313944

Comment: Mesopotamians 6000 Y.A, and later the Romans 2000Y.A mentioned [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=-Hk9eDMLFFkC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA31&dq=romans%20drain%20marsh&pg=PA31#v=onepage&q=romans%20drain%20marsh&f=false)

Comment: There's evidence in Neolithic times, I believe.  After all, ditches are the simplest way.

Comment: Things such as cutting peat for fuel, killing animals (affecting grazing), and cutting/uprooting plants (for food or other purposes) might all affect marshlands. Are you specifically interested in deliberate draining, rather than other human actions that affected marshlands?